# I/O Errors during xubuntu install on HP Stream 13-c002dx laptop. Am I hosed?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive, xubuntu

I have an old [HP Stream 13-c002dx](https://www.ifixit.com/Device/HP_Stream_13-c002dx) that is becoming increasingly unstable under Windows 8.1. I downloaded the xubuntu 22.04 live disk onto a usb drive, and I've successfully pulled all of the data that I care about off the drive, although there were some I/O errors during the copy.

Notes about the HP Stream 13: it's a *cheap* celeron laptop with a 32GB eMMC hard drive integrated into the motherboard. If the drive is toast, I'll have to replace the motherboard or throw the laptop away.

The drive is `/dev/mmcblk0`. Here's the partition table according to `gdisk`:

```
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
1            2048            534527    260.0 MiB   EF00  EFI system partition
2          534528            796671    128.0 MiB   0C01  Microsoft reserved ...
3          796672          45119487    21.1 GiB    0700  Basic data partition
4        45119488          61077503    7.6 GiB     2700  Basic data partition
```

Running a quick scan on the hard drive via the BIOS system diagnostics screen shows no errors. I think this is a bit suspicious due to the I/O errors during file copy, but it does indicate to me that the drive is not on the brink of failure.

Under **Install Xubuntu 22.04.LTS**, I click *Continue* at the **Write the changes to disks** dialog. The Timezone window shows up, but several seconds later I get a dialog that reads

```
Error!!!
Input/Output error during write on /dev/mmcblk0
[Retry] [Ignore] [Cancel]
```

Sometimes the installer freezes at this point, requiring `xkill`, if it doesn't freeze, clicking any of the buttons pops up the error

```
Failed to create a file system
The efi file system creation in partition #1 of MMC/SD cart #1 (mmcblk0) failed
[OK]
```

Clicking `[OK]` allows me to cancel the file system creation and cancel the install.

Regardless of what I try, the partitions are **not** touched. I've even tried removing them using gparted. Again, I get I/O errors.

I *do* think that the hard drive is suspect; I was hoping that the process of formatting the hard drive would mark and blacklist bad sectors, and I would be able to use the laptop until the drive entirely craps out. It seems that I can't write to the partition table, but it can't be totally corrupt, because I can still reboot to Windows, and I can still see the partitions.

It feels like something is actively keeping me from writing to the partition table. It's obviously *not* an issue of unplugged cables or something, because the drive is integrated into the board. Any thoughts about what I should try next?

The excerpt from `/var/kern/log` shows the I/O errors after I try to write changes to the disk during the install process.

```
Nov  4 13:58:01 xubuntu kernel: [2335561.548945] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Nov  4 13:58:01 xubuntu kernel: [2335561.548981] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 0, lost async page write
Nov  4 13:58:01 xubuntu kernel: [2335561.550726] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 61079544 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Nov  4 13:58:01 xubuntu kernel: [2335561.550755] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 7634943, lost async page write
Nov  4 13:58:01 xubuntu kernel: [2335561.551988] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
Nov  4 13:58:01 xubuntu kernel: [2335561.552016] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 0, lost async page write
Nov  4 13:58:01 xubuntu kernel: [2335561.557041]  mmcblk0: p1 p2 p3 p4
Nov  4 13:58:01 xubuntu kernel: [2335561.562617] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 3 prio class 0
Nov  4 13:58:01 xubuntu kernel: [2335561.562632] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 0, lost async page write
Nov  4 13:58:01 xubuntu kernel: [2335561.562653] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 1, lost async page write
Nov  4 13:58:01 xubuntu kernel: [2335561.562661] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 2, lost async page write
Nov  4 13:58:01 xubuntu kernel: [2335561.562854] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 61079528 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 3 prio class 0
Nov  4 13:58:01 xubuntu kernel: [2335561.562865] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 7634941, lost async page write
Nov  4 13:58:01 xubuntu kernel: [2335561.562880] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 7634942, lost async page write
Nov  4 13:58:01 xubuntu kernel: [2335561.562893] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 7634943, lost async page write
Nov  4 13:58:01 xubuntu kernel: [2335561.575989] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 0 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 5 prio class 0
Nov  4 13:58:01 xubuntu kernel: [2335561.576007] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0, logical block 0, lost async page write
Nov  4 13:58:01 xubuntu kernel: [2335561.576926] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 61079512 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 5 prio class 0
Nov  4 14:00:28 xubuntu kernel: [2335708.906219] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 2048 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 128 prio class 0
Nov  4 14:00:28 xubuntu kernel: [2335708.906239] buffer_io_error: 9 callbacks suppressed
Nov  4 14:00:28 xubuntu kernel: [2335708.906241] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0p1, logical block 0, lost async page write
Nov  4 14:00:28 xubuntu kernel: [2335708.906270] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0p1, logical block 1, lost async page write
Nov  4 14:00:28 xubuntu kernel: [2335708.906278] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0p1, logical block 2, lost async page write
Nov  4 14:00:28 xubuntu kernel: [2335708.906285] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0p1, logical block 3, lost async page write
Nov  4 14:00:28 xubuntu kernel: [2335708.906293] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0p1, logical block 4, lost async page write
Nov  4 14:00:28 xubuntu kernel: [2335708.906300] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0p1, logical block 5, lost async page write
Nov  4 14:00:28 xubuntu kernel: [2335708.906306] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0p1, logical block 6, lost async page write
Nov  4 14:00:28 xubuntu kernel: [2335708.906318] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0p1, logical block 7, lost async page write
Nov  4 14:00:28 xubuntu kernel: [2335708.906331] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0p1, logical block 8, lost async page write
Nov  4 14:00:28 xubuntu kernel: [2335708.906344] Buffer I/O error on dev mmcblk0p1, logical block 9, lost async page write
Nov  4 14:00:28 xubuntu kernel: [2335708.911993] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 3072 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 128 prio class 0
Nov  4 14:00:28 xubuntu kernel: [2335708.917732] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 4096 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 128 prio class 0
Nov  4 14:00:28 xubuntu kernel: [2335708.923440] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 5120 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 128 prio class 0
Nov  4 14:00:28 xubuntu kernel: [2335708.929061] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 6144 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 128 prio class 0
Nov  4 14:00:28 xubuntu kernel: [2335708.934865] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 7168 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 128 prio class 0
Nov  4 14:00:28 xubuntu kernel: [2335708.941732] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 8192 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 128 prio class 0
Nov  4 14:00:28 xubuntu kernel: [2335708.946324] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 9216 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x4800 phys_seg 128 prio class 0
Nov  4 14:00:28 xubuntu kernel: [2335708.946632] blk_update_request: I/O error, dev mmcblk0, sector 10240 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 5 prio class 0
Nov  4 14:02:49 xubuntu kernel: [2335849.802252]  mmcblk0: p1 p2 p3 p4
```

Comment: The drive is dead or dying replace the drive and try again.

Comment: It's certainly not dead. It's also not replaceable (at least not without replacing the motherboard). I agree that it's *probably* dying, but it's a cheap laptop, and I wouldn't put it past HP to put some roadblocks in the way of OS replacement. It's worth a few hours of my time to tinker with it before I throw it away. FWIW, it passed HP's 'Extensive' storage test, which supposedly read every block on the drive. I'm hoping this post will catch the eye of some hypothetical guy in Des Moines who has installed linux  on 5 HP Streams and knows some magic to get into a hidden part of the BIOS ;-)

Comment: You have a hardware issue no matter how much you want it not to be true. Good luck.

Comment: I agree with @David; this looks like a hardware problem to me. That said, you might be able to squeeze some more life out of the laptop by using it with an external drive. That's not optimal, but it might be worth considering.